# Content from console.writeline do not work with Polly

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, polly

Goal:
Show the message "show error" after 3 attempt.

Problem:
What part of the code do not work in order to achieve the goal.

```cs
using Polly;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsolePollyTest2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var maxRetryAttempts = 3;
            var pauseBetweenFailures = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

            Policy
                .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
                .Or<TaskCanceledException>()
                .WaitAndRetryAsync(maxRetryAttempts, i => pauseBetweenFailures)
                .ExecuteAsync(PersistApplicationData2)
                .ContinueWith(x =>
                {
                    if (x.Exception != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("show error");
                    }
                });
        }


        private static async Task PersistApplicationData2()
        {
            int ddfd = 3;
            var df = ddfd / 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Show data");
            await Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to await your task.

Comment: .... Any sample? I have applied task at PersistApplicationData2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Await your task to be run first also your policy says in case of `HttpRequestException` or `TaskCanceledException` retry policy will work and your method has no any exception of those.

If you want to test retry policy you can do some thing like this:

```cs
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var maxRetryAttempts = 3;
    var pauseBetweenFailures = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

    await Policy
        .Handle<HttpRequestException>()
        .Or<Exception>() //if any exception raised will try agian
        .Or<TaskCanceledException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(maxRetryAttempts, i => pauseBetweenFailures)
        .ExecuteAsync( PersistApplicationData2)
        .ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            if (x.Exception != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("show error");
            }
            //success
        },  scheduler: TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Comment: Please do not mix `await` and `ContinueWith`. Please prefer `try` `catch` instead.